# How to connect Rpi4B to a HDMI Touch Screen?

Tags: power, pi-4, alternative-power

I have recently invested in a [HDMI touchscreen from Amazon](https://www.amazon.com.au/LANDZO-Touch-Display-Raspberry-Banana/dp/B07VFFBDY5/ref=sr_1_7?keywords=raspberry%20pi%20screen&qid=1588725607&sr=8-7), and a Raspberry Pi 4,
For the touchscreen to work it must be connected via GPIO, however my pi cannot supply enough power to it from my [usb power bank](https://www.officeworks.com.au/shop/officeworks/p/keji-15000mah-powerbank-black-copb15bk#specifications) which can provide enough power for the pi but not the display. As the display has a usb port for power as well as GPIO, I attempted powering the display from usb, however this caused the pi to boot up, hinting that there is some connection causing power to go into the pi from GPIO, thus I question whether it is safe to power the pi from GPIO and USB-C simultaneously?

Update (6/05/20): I am asking this question as when I power it from the USB-C on the Pi alone it gives me a yellow lightning bolt in the top right-hand corner.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107726/discussion-on-question-by-big-bob-how-to-connect-rpi4b-to-a-hdmi-touch-screen).

Answer (score 2):

***Question***

*How to connect Rpi to a HDMI Touch LCD Display?*

---

***Answer***

*Suggested connection*

[image: hdmi display connection]

---

*HDMI Touch Screen Wiring Diagram*

[image: hdmi 5"]

---

***References***

(1) [AliExpress Waveshare 5 inch HDMI LCD (G) resistive monitor touch screen LCD 800X480 - US$50](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32864207136.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000023.1.294d1922TBIbKV)

(2) [Amazon 5" LCD Touch Display for Rpi - Landzo](https://www.amazon.com.au/LANDZO-Touch-Display-Raspberry-Banana/dp/B07VFFBDY5/ref=sr_1_7?keywords=raspberry%20pi%20screen&qid=1588725607&sr=8-7)

(3) [AliExpress Waveshare Rpi 7" HDMI LCD IPS Capacitive Touch Screen - US$57](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32470090943.html)

(4) [XPT2046 Touch Screen Controller Datasheet - Shenzhen XPTek](http://grobotronics.com/images/datasheets/xpt2046-datasheet.pdf)

(5) [WaveShare 5" HDMI LCD (G) Wiki](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/5inch_HDMI_LCD_(G)?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000023.14.3ed723d92pGqqt)

(6) [WaveShare 5" HDMI LCD (G) User Manual](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/a/a9/5inch_HDMI_LCD_G_User_Manual_en.pdf)

---

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - XPT2046 Touch Screen Controller Block Diagram and Operation*

[image: xpt2046]

---

*Appendix B - WaveShare 7" HDMI LCD Touch Screen Selection Guide*

[image: LCD Selection Guide]

---

*End of Answer*

---