# Is it possible to connect two touch screens to the Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, touchscreen, screen

So I know the Pi 4 will support dual monitors out of the box no problem. I am wondering if it will support dual *touch* screens as well. If so is there any particular issues or configuration needed to get both touch screens to work.

Comment: Yes, some HDMI touch screens can do that, to Rpi4B. See Appendix B of my answer to the following question for more details: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112123/how-to-connect-rpi4b-to-a-hdmi-touch-screen. Cheers.